# Frames per second using WPF's DrawingContext class

Tags: c#, wpf

I've got an example app which draws Rectangles, Lines etc. using the DrawContext instance of the OnRender override of a Control class. This control is repainted every 10 milliseconds by calling InvalidateVisual (I can post the source to anybody who's interested). I calculate the Frames per second (FPS) by measuring the time between each call of OnRender.

However, this figure for FPS is incorrect. Just by looking at the app I can see that the figure given for FPS is higher than the number of times per second that the app repaints itself. This is because "When you use a [DrawingContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.drawingcontext.aspx) object's draw commands, you are actually storing a set of rendering instructions (although the exact storage mechanism depends on the type of object that supplies the DrawingContext) that will later be used by the graphics system; you are not drawing to the screen in real-time."

So what I would like to know is if there is any event I can subscribe to, or any other way, to ascertain how many times per second my WPF app/control is generating a new bitmap and drawing it to the screen? Is there any bitmap buffer held by the "graphics system" which we can access?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need to use is the [CompositionTarget.Rendering](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.compositiontarget.rendering.aspx) event that is called every frame.